# CakePHP 4.4: a table has many itself

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have the `NursingRegisters` table, which in addition to the `id` field has the `date` field. More than one record can be inserted for the same date.

Now I would like to group the records by `date`. Normally I could use `\Cake\Collection\Collection::groupBy()`, but in my case it is not possible, because then I want to do data pagination specifically for the `date` field.

For now I understand that I have to start from here:

```php
$Query = $this->NursingRegisters->find()
   ->select(['id', 'date'])
   ->orderDesc('date')
   ->group('NursingRegisters.date')
   ->limit(30);
```

This will return me the set of various dates (or, more precisely, one entity per `date`).

Now, somehow, I should make this main entity contain the sub-entities with the same date.
This can be done in various ways, presumably a sub query.

So I'm trying to do this. First I define an association for the table:

```php
$this->hasMany('NursingRegistersByDay')
    ->setClassName('NursingRegisters')
    ->setStrategy('subquery')
    ->setForeignKey('date');
```

Then modifying the main query with a `contain()`:

```php
$Query = $this->NursingRegisters->find()
   ->select(['id', 'date'])
   ->contain('NursingRegistersByDay', function (Query $Query): Query {
        return $Query->select(['id', 'date']);
    })
   ->orderDesc('date')
   ->group('NursingRegisters.date')
   ->limit(30);
```

But I don't get the desired result:

```
SELECT 
  NursingRegisters.id AS NursingRegisters__id, 
  NursingRegisters.date AS NursingRegisters__date 
FROM 
  nursing_registers NursingRegisters 
GROUP BY 
  NursingRegisters.date 
ORDER BY 
  date DESC 
LIMIT 
  20 OFFSET 0

SELECT 
  NursingRegistersByDay.id AS NursingRegistersByDay__id, 
  NursingRegistersByDay.date AS NursingRegistersByDay__date 
FROM 
  nursing_registers NursingRegistersByDay 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      (NursingRegisters.id) 
    FROM 
      nursing_registers NursingRegisters 
    GROUP BY 
      NursingRegisters.date, 
      NursingRegisters.id 
    ORDER BY 
      date DESC 
    LIMIT 
      20 OFFSET 0
  ) NursingRegisters ON NursingRegistersByDay.date = NursingRegisters.id

SELECT 
  (
    COUNT(*)
  ) AS count 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      NursingRegisters.id AS NursingRegisters__id, 
      NursingRegisters.date AS NursingRegisters__date 
    FROM 
      nursing_registers NursingRegisters 
    GROUP BY 
      NursingRegisters.date
  ) count_source
```

What am I doing wrong? Is my idea conceptually valid?

Of course the problem is here:

```
ON NursingRegistersByDay.date = NursingRegisters.id
```

---

So it seems to me that the problem is in the `bindingKey`.

But by setting the `bindingKey` with `select` strategy I get:

```
2023-09-18 17:29:33 error: [TypeError] Illegal offset type in /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/EagerLoader.php on line 841
Stack Trace:
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/EagerLoader.php:813
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/EagerLoader.php:634
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Query.php:1148
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Datasource/QueryTrait.php:288
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Query.php:1096
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Datasource/Paging/NumericPaginator.php:190
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php:957
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/src/Controller/NursingRegistersController.php:88
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php:547
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/ControllerFactory.php:139
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/ControllerFactory.php:114
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php:320
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:86
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/authorization/src/Middleware/AuthorizationMiddleware.php:129
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:82
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/authentication/src/Middleware/AuthenticationMiddleware.php:124
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:82
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Middleware/CsrfProtectionMiddleware.php:174
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:82
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Middleware/BodyParserMiddleware.php:157
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:82
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php:186
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:82
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/AssetMiddleware.php:68
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:82
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php:131
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:82
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/src/Middleware/DebugKitMiddleware.php:60
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:82
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:67
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php:90
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/webroot/index.php:26

Request URL: /nursing-registers/indexGroupedByDay
Referer URL: http://localhost/climat/login?redirect=%2Fnursing-registers%2FindexGroupedByDay
```

Instead, with `subquery` strategy:

```
Request URL: /nursing-registers/indexGroupedByDay
Referer URL: http://localhost/climat/login?redirect=%2Fnursing-registers%2FindexGroupedByDay
2023-09-18 17:31:49 error: [TypeError] Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Association/Loader/SelectLoader.php on line 522
Stack Trace:
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Statement/CallbackStatement.php:63
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/ResultSet.php:447
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/ResultSet.php:261
- [internal]:??
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Collection/CollectionTrait.php:690
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/ResultSet.php:577
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php:785
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php:712
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php:745
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php:708
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php:652
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php:453
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Renderer/WebExceptionRenderer.php:269
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php:162
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php:135
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:82
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/src/Middleware/DebugKitMiddleware.php:60
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:82
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:67
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php:90
- /home/mirko/Server/climat/webroot/index.php:26

Request URL: /nursing-registers/indexGroupedByDay
Referer URL: http://localhost/climat/login?redirect=%2Fnursing-registers%2FindexGroupedByDay
```